# Do drones charge too while their rover recharges its battery?

Tags: surviving-mars

After using a rover and its drones, I recalled them inside and put the rover on charge. Do the drones charge while the rover is charging or must they be deployed to be charged individually?

[image]

Comment: Hey @Galabyca, I edited this question a bit for grammar. If you think I changed the meaning of what you were asking please roll it back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have the rover charged and deploy the drones and then they will go up to the rover and charge themselves.

Additionally, if your rover is charged you can select the interact feature, click on the battery depleted drone and it will "save" it. (Scan it and bring it into the rover).